# Get other record for specific Date

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following case:

two tables, same structure.

```
t1 --> oDate datetime, oVal int<br>
t2 --> oDate datetime, oVal int<br>
```

let say the data are:

t1:

```
---------------------
oDate         oVal
---------------------
2016-07-30    30
2016-07-31    40
2016-08-01    35
2016-08-02    50
```

t2:

```
--------------------
oDate         oVal
---------------------
2016-07-30    56
2016-07-31    34
```

t2 is empty since '2016-08-01',  both field `oDate` and `oVal`.

I want to have the following result:

```
---------------------------
oDate          oVal1     oVal2
---------------------------
2016-07-30     30        56
2016-07-31     40        34
2016-08-01     35        35
2016-08-02     50        50
```

because table `t2` is empty since '2016-08-01', the the value for `oVal2` is copy from `oVal1`.

How can I do that with SQL Query?
Thank you.

Comment: What if t1 is missing some dates from t2?

Comment: t1 is always available.

Comment: Then @Paweł 's query is  a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `left join` and `case` as follows:

```
SELECT T1.oDate, T1.oVal oVal1, CASE WHEN T2.oVal IS NULL THEN T1.oVal ELSE T2.oVal END oVal2
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.oDate=T2.oDate
```

Take a look at demo:

```
WITH T1 AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    (CONVERT(datetime, '2016-07-30'), 30),
    (CONVERT(datetime, '2016-07-31'), 40),
    (CONVERT(datetime, '2016-08-01'), 35),
    (CONVERT(datetime, '2016-08-02'), 50)) T(oDate, oVal)
), T2 AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    (CONVERT(datetime, '2016-07-30'), 56),
    (CONVERT(datetime, '2016-07-31'), 34)) T(oDate, oVal)
)
SELECT T1.oDate, T1.oVal oVal1, CASE WHEN T2.oVal IS NULL THEN T1.oVal ELSE T2.oVal END oVal2
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.oDate=T2.oDate
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. But how can I choose to "activate" LEFT JOIN when the date is more than '2016-07-31'?

Comment: Probably OP needs FULL JOIN.

Comment: If date is more than '2016-07-31', `LEFT JOIN` produces NULL on T2's side. That is the case for `CASE` expression. As said, T1 is always available.

Comment: Do u have a situation like, all the data missing in 2nd table after a particular date and you want to copy the 1st table data for those missing ..?

Comment: Hi, t2 will always blank start from 2016-08-01

Comment: Okay then, @PawełDyl solution will work, you can use 'CASE' statement.

Comment: yes, @PawełDyl is the solution. Cheers, :) .. But regarding my question on comment sec, "how can I choose to "activate" LEFT JOIN when the date is more than '2016-07-31'?". Is it possible?

Comment: you can add " WHERE t1.odate > '2016-07-31' " at last just after join condition.

Answer (score 0):

sel
a.odate,a.oval,Coalesce(b.oval,a.oval)
from t1 a
left join 
t2 b
on a.odate = b.odate